# convert one date with timezone to another date with timezone using javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone

I have one date time

Date_Dubai=2017-12-29 01:00 AM Asia/Dubai

and i have to convert it to "Asia/Kolkota" in  "Date_Dubai" format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: please give in pure javascript

Comment: look at the 3rd response

Comment: oh thats cool thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 dt = new Date();
 localTime = dt.getTime(); //current localtime in milisecond.
 localOffset = dt.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; 
//getTimezoneOffset() returns in minutes so converting it into millisecond(*60000).
```

The time-zone offset is the difference, in minutes, between UTC and local time. Note that this means that the offset is positive if the local timezone is behind UTC and negative if it is ahead.[(Doc)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

Get the current UTC time, by adding the local time zone offset to the local time.

```
 utc = localTime + localOffset;
```

After getting UTC time, get the destination city's UTC offset in hours. Here Dubai offset is +4 hours.

```
    offset = 4; // GST (Gulf Standard Time) ahead +4 hours from utc
    dubaiTime = utc + (3600000*offset); // convert offset into milisecond and add to UTC time.
    newTime = new Date(dubaiTime); 
    console.log(newTime);
```

More info about [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Please explain why your solution works, if it does, to improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: @EricHauenstein Hope it is fine now.

Comment: -1. This approach is given often, and is *always* wrong.  You cannot convince the `Date` object to change its time zone.  All you're doing here is picking a different point in time.  Consider if you called `getTimezoneOffset()` on the resulting `newTime` variable - it would still be that of the local computer - not Dubai.  This leads to errors in time zones that have transitions, such as daylight saving time or a change in standard time.